# Event QComboBox to Custom QLineEdit

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qcombobox, qlineedit

The Problem: I have a custom event on `QLineEdit` inside a custom `QComboBox` and only specific events are being passed from `QComboBox` to `QLineEdit` when I want. I can't get tab to be passed.

I want when an event passed to `QComboBox` it will be passed to the `QComboBox->lineEdit()`.

```cpp
QCustomCombo::QCustomCombo():
    m_lineEdit(new QCustomLineEdit)
{
    setEditable(true);
    setLineEdit(m_lineEdit);
}

bool QCustomCombo::event(QEvent * event)
{
    if(event->type() == QEvent::KeyPress)
    {
        QKeyEvent * keyEvent = static_cast<QKeyEvent *>(event);
        if(keyEvent->key() == Qt::Key_tab)
        {
            //pass to lineEdit();
            //I have tried 'return true/false and QWidget::event(event)'
            //I have also tried commenting out QCustomCombo::event, same problem
        }
    }
    return QWidget::event(event);
}
```

QCustomLineEdit

```cpp
bool QCustomLineEdit::event(QEvent * event)
{
    if(event->type() == QEvent::KeyPress)
    {
        QKeyEvent * keyEvent = static_cast<QKeyEvent *>(event);
        if(keyEvent->key() == Qt::Key_tab)
        {
            //Do custom Stuff
            return true;
        }
        if(keyEvent->key() == Qt::Key_Right)
        {
            //Do custom Stuff
            return true;
        }
    }
    return QWidget::event(event);
}
```

The `QLineEdit` has a custom event for left and right arrow and tab. Only the arrows get passed. But I can't get the tab to pass to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `QApplication::notify`

```
bool QCustomCombo::event(QEvent * event)
{
    if(event->type() == QEvent::KeyPress)
    {
        QKeyEvent * keyEvent = static_cast<QKeyEvent *>(event);
        if(keyEvent->key() == Qt::Key_Tab)
        {
            qApp->notify(m_lineEdit, event);
            return true;
        }
    }
    return QWidget::event(event);
}
```

Comment: How do I get access to qApp functions? I tried `QCustomCombo : private QApplication`, but that breaks my `connect()` lines. The QCombo is located inside a mainwindow.cpp created by a main.cpp (main.cpp is where I have QApplication instance).

Comment: @DevilGale it is not necessary to inherit, just include the header: `#include <QApplication>`. `QApplication::instance()` is a singleton that can be used with the qApp macro.

Answer (score 1):

> I want when an event passed to QComboBox it will be passed to the
>   QComboBox->lineEdit().

[installEventFilter()](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#installEventFilter) is your friend here.  It allows object A to install an event filter on another object B, so that before object B's `event(QEvent *)` method gets called, object A's `eventFilter(QObject *, QEvent *)` method will be called first, so that object A can decide how to handle the event (and whether or not the event should be passed on to object B afterwards).

You can use that so that your `CustomCombo` can see and react to events that would otherwise go directly to the `QComboBox.